# Upgrade from Jetpack Compose 1.0.5 to 1.1.0: Error launching app

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have just upgraded a fully functional Jetpack compose mobile app from Compose 1.0.5 to 1.1.0. It builds with no errors and no warnings. However, it does not launch anymore.

Problems Tab in Android Studio indicates that are `104 problems` related with `Choreographer.java ~/Android/Sdk/sources/android-31/android/view`

build.gradle (:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.1.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

    // Room libraries
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.1"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.1"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.1"

    // DataStore Preferences
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0"

    // Hilt dependencies
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'

    // Navigation dependency
    // implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha10"

    // Accompanist Jetpack Navigation Compose Animation
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:0.19.0"

}
```

build.gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin
        kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
        compose_version = '1.1.0'
        hilt_version = '2.40.5'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried running my sample project with your gradle file, and it runs fine. First if all I suggest you updating **accompanist-navigation-animation** to **0.23.0**, if this didn't help - start removing parts of your app until it runs fine to find the problem.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Thanks. You were right. The problem was in the Accompanist version which for Compose 1.1.0 is 0.23.0. If you don't mind, I'll answer the question alerting all to the fact that there are libraries (namely Accompanist) that Android Studio does not detect newer versions.

Comment: Sure, go for it

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @PhilipDukhov the problem was in the Accompanist version which for Compose 1.1.0 is 0.23.0. In fact, there are multiple versions of Accompanist for the different versions of Compose, you can find it [here](https://google.github.io/accompanist/#compose-versions).

Important to note that Android Studio does not alert us to newer versions of some libraries (namely, Accompanist), so we must be aware of this fact.

Comment: You can use this plugin: https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin to check your dependencies for updates